# Delete every second occurrence in a list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, algorithm

I am doing some python lately and came up with this exercise if someone could help:

Delete every second occurrence (i.e., 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc.) occurrence of term in s.
The above code is not working and I am trying to print out `aabcdaxyaa112`

```
def delete_occurence(s, term):
    s = [s[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
    s_length = len(s)
 
    for item in range(1, s_length):
        if (s[item] == term) and (item % 2 == 0):
            s.remove(s[item])
    print(''.join(s))
            

delete_occurence("aabcdaaaxyaa11aa2", "aa")
```

Comment: seems that you're iterating using indices but you're using remove which shifts the index, then it won't get past the first occurrences

Comment: how do you want to deal with example s = "aaa" , term = "aa" , I mean what in case there is overlapping ? the desired answer is "aaa" or "a" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can't work because of many things:

- `remove` only removes the first occurrence of a string
- the indices are shifted once you remove something

My approach would be to split the string according to the term, then recreate list elements, inserting the term only one out of 2 times. And handle the corner case of the last element.

```
def delete_occurence(s, term):
    # split string, get rid of "term" strings
    toks = s.split(term)
    rval = []
    # loop on the split list of strings
    for i,t in enumerate(toks):
        # add string
        rval.append(t)
        if i%2==0 and i!=len(toks)-1:
            # add term only if not last item and if i is even
            rval.append(term)
    # recreate the string from the list
    return "".join(rval)

# prints aabcdaxyaa112
print(delete_occurence("aabcdaaaxyaa11aa2", "aa"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like one approach would be to simply find the indexes where you have *term* with regex. Then just remove those parts of your string.
Note that if you're enforcing the effects on the same string (such as code below), you need to keep an offset, to know the updated value of the *term* indices.

```
import re

def delete_occurence(s, term):
    indices = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(term, s)]
    indices_odd = indices[1::2]

    offset = 0
    for indice in indices_odd:
        indice -= offset
        s = s[:indice] + s[indice + len(term):]
        offset += len(term)

    print(s)
  
delete_occurence("aabcdaaaxyaa11aa2", "aa")
```